# Nginx 401 Authorization required error on page load

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have configured nginx server with http basic auth. By default opening homepage shows 401 Authorization required error.

When i clear browser cache or hard refresh using ctrl + f5 then i get login prompt and everything works ok.

How to get login promt by default on page load?

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved this issue by removing service workers from my page.